# Replace map for-each by classic for-loop?

Tags: java

Java 8

here some snippet:

```
String createSelector(Map.Entry<String, Map<String, String>> seriesMapEntry) {
   for (Map.Entry<String,String> column : seriesMapEntry.getValue().entrySet()) {
        String expr = column.getValue();
         // some code here
   }
}
```

Nice. It's work fine.

Is it possible to iterate **seriesMapEntry** without `for-each` loop? E.g use classic for loop (iterate by index).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no index to iterate over. You can, however, use an explicit `Iterator` and a while loop:

```
String createSelector(Map.Entry<String, Map<String, String>> seriesMapEntry) {
   Iterator<Map.Entry<String,String>> iter = seriesMapEntry.getValue().entrySet().iterator();
   while (iter.hasNext ()) {
        Map.Entry<String,String> column = iter.next ();
        String expr = column.getValue();
         // some code here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The classic for loop in this case did not iterate "by index" (as there's no index in a Map or Set), but used an iterator:

```
for (Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> iter = seriesMapEntry.getValue().entrySet().iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
    Map.Entry<String,String> column = iter.next();
    // some code here
}
```